# Dropdown Menu behind gallery plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, gallery

The website is http://columbiamillworks.com/photo-gallery/arches/
If you hover over "photo gallery" in the main nav, the dropdown is positioned behind the galleary plugin and you cannot click any links below the gallery-wrap. I have tried using z-index to no avail.

Any idea why those links aren't clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `z-index` from `#main-nav`.

It causes `z-index` of 100, while its children have `z-index` more than 100.

Removing it will resolve your problem.

Comment: That did it! I figured it was something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thar's cause the gallery wrapper is deeper in the DOM tree than the menu.

Therefore, you'll need to apply the z-index to the parent containers of both the menu and the gallery, which are on the same DOM level.

In your case that would be:

```
#headerwrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#body {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; // so the gallery container is actually lower on z axis then the header
}
```